OAuth1Authenticator class not found
I'm trying to use OAuth 1.0 authentication with RestSharp. Visual Studio can't seem to find the OAuth1Authenticator class. What's causing this issue?

using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth;
using RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth.Extensions;

...


            var options = new RestClientOptions("https://example.com")
            {
                Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
            };



For the record, this is specifically a problem with version 111.0.0.

I’m voting to close this question because this was an accidental bug in one particular version of the library that has been fixed.

Found the issue. Looks like RestSharp hasn't updated the documentation on their website. The correct syntax is as follows:
OAuth1Auth.ForRequestToken(consumerKey, consumerSecret)


https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/pull/2200 So now the question is: why is a PR called "new docs" modifying the public API? There's also a follow up commit by the same author that addresses a OAuth1Authenticator issue but applies it to the new OAuth1Auth class.

It was an accidental change in v111.0, and it is reverted in v111.1.

I'm not exactly sure but I think there is a problem with your Using, restrict the code a bit more. do you have a chance to use it like this?
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;


That still didn't work either. Still not recognizing the class
